# Submit varStatus values is sending always the same value

Tags: jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute="someModel">
        <c:forEach items="${someModel.someList}" var="row" varStatus="status">
                 Id ${row.id} status ${status.index}
                 <form:input path="id" type="hidden" value="${row.id}"/>
                 <input type="submit" id="save"  name="_eventId_someFunction" value="Save"/>
                 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${row.id}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </form:form>
```

Having this piece of code, I see that the `Id ${row.id} status ${status.index}` is showing different values, but the action `_eventId_someFunction` recieves always the first one. What could be the problem?

I am using spring web flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is inside the form. So each time you submit, you submit all the inputs (the IDs of all the rows), and not just the ones that are in the same row as the submit button you clicked.

Put the form inside the loop, and everything should work as expected.